# Can't get Json data to display using coffee script in Play2.4 based web app with Mysql/Java

Tags: java, mysql, json, playframework, coffeescript

I am using play 2.4 framework to create a very basic web app. Here are my codes:

`Application.java`

```
package controllers;
import play.*;
import play.db.ebean.Transactional;
import play.mvc.*;
import views.html.*;
import models.Players;
import play.data.Form;
import java.util.List;
import com.avaje.ebean.Model;
import static play.libs.Json.toJson;


public class Application extends Controller {

@Transactional
public Result index() {
    return ok(index.render());
}
@Transactional
public Result addPlayer() {
    Players player = Form.form(Players.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    player.save();
    return redirect(routes.Application.index());
}

@Transactional
public Result getPlayer() {
    List<Players> players = Players.FIND.findList();
    return ok(toJson(players));
}}
```

`Players.java`

```
package models;
import javax.persistence.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.Model;


@Entity

@Table(name = "player_info")
public class Players extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int id;

    public String name;
   public static Model.Finder<Integer, Players> FIND = new Model.Finder<>(Players.class);
}
```

`Index.scala.html`

```
@main("Welcome to TSI") {

     <div>

     <script type='text/javascrips' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/main.js")'></script>

     <ul id="players_list" ></ul>

      </div>

     <form action="@routes.Application.addPlayer()" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <button type="submit">Add player</button>
     </form>
}
```

`Routes`

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

POST    /player                     controllers.Application.addPlayer()   

GET     /players                    controllers.Application.getPlayer()  

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

`Main.coffee`

```
$ ->
   $.get "/players", (players) ->
      $.each players, (index, player) ->
         $('#players_list').append $("<li>").text player.name
```

Data gets saved/retrieved from DB perfectly when user inputs from the web form. But while getting the data from JSON to HTML, it shows nothing (empty list).

I really tried to use JS and other coffee scripts but none worked, so not sure where I am going wrong.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is `/players` mapped to `getPlayer` in `routes`?

Comment: yes, adding routes file too

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a typo. Instead of

```
<script type='text/javascrips' ...
```

it should be

```
<script type='text/javascript' ...
```

Comment: I realised that after posting, but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using `defer = "defer"` parameter in script tag as it was not recognising the list tags and have to wait for them to be declared.